# Apache Wicket - DropDownChoice live search

Tags: java, wicket

I have a `DropDownChoice` with a very large number of options. 
How can I add live search capability to `DropDownChoice` to easily search and select items?

Comment: If you switch to Ajax as a search term there are lots of hits: [Apache ajax  DropDown "live search"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Apache+ajax++DropDown+"live+search"). But not too much for Wicket. Maybe Apache Wicket is not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Select2](https://select2.org/) JavaScript plugin. There is a [Wicket integration of Select 2.](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/tree/master/select2-parent)  The maven coordinates are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>wicketstuff-select2</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wicket's DropDownChoice produces the plain HTML `<select`> element. For live search you will need to use some JavaScript solution.

If you happen to use/prefer Bootstrap CSS framework then you may also find https://wb8.teliclab.info/select useful. It is part of wicket-bootstrap-extensions module at https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/tree/wicket-7.x/bootstrap-extensions.